# this.props is not a function react.js

Tags: reactjs, function

Why I receive the error `_this.props.onLogin is not a function`. I tried it also with binding...
Here the relevant part of my child-class, named `Login`:

```
onValidSubmit = (formData) => {
  console.log('logging from onvalidSubmit');
  this.props.onLogin(formData);   
};
```

My parent class is calling this component like. It seems that the props are not passed to the component.

```
<Route exact path='/login' render={props=> <Login  onLogin = {this.onLogin}/>}/>
```

And the calling function in the parent class is:

```
onLogin = (formData) => {
  console.log('onLogin of Main');
  this.props.logInUser(formData);
};
```

But unfortunately this onLogin function will never be called. I receive the error `_this.props.onLogin is not a function` in my child component??? 
Arnold

Comment: Your code looks fine. Can you please create a demo version

Comment: Is `formData` the prop your passing in? And i'm assuming `logInUser` in a function your'e calling?

Comment: I ask the above as if `onLogin` and `logInUser` are function you shouldn't be calling them like `this.props.onLogin(formData).. you just call them like `this.onLogin(formData)`

Comment: Yes right. But it seems that the props are not passed. I tried it like:
<code> <Route exact path='/login' render={props=> <Login {...props} onLogin = {this.onLogin} test={"xxx"}/>}/></code>
And if I call console.log(this.props.test) in the child component  it give me alwas undefined...

Comment: i'm assuming `Route` in your component name? Can you give a list of all props you are using for this component?

Comment: No I was using React Router. Login is the component name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide `{...props}` in your router.

Replace

```
<Route exact path='/login' render={props=> <Login  onLogin = {this.onLogin}/>}/>
```

to

```
<Route exact path='/login' render={props => <Login {...props} onLogin = {this.onLogin}/>}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems that the props are not passed. why? If i pass a prop like test={"test"} it will not be passed...

Comment: If we don't write {...props} then only onLogin will get passed to Login component, all other values that router passes to the component by default, will not be available inside Login component. that's y we use spread operator over props to pass all other props to login components as well.

It is working fine right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all. It was an error defining the BrowserRouter. I defined it twice, therefore this behavior. 
Arnold